# Angular: Buttons action make the same call

Tags: javascript, angular

I have in a footer 3 buttons. When I click "next" I redirect to another page. But when I click on "Edit" I would only enable some field, while it does the same action of the next button ( so redirect to another page ).

In your opinion why I have this behaviour?

```
<div class="row">
<div class="card-footer-sx col">
    <button class="btn back-btn" href="javascript:void(0)"
        (click)="goBack()">Back</button>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer-center col" style="display: contents"
         href="javascript:void(0)">
        <button class="btn next-btn float-center"
            (click)="enableEditing()">Edit</button>
    </div>

    <div class="card-footer-dx col " >
        <div class="pointer flex-end">
            <div class="container-next-button">
                <div class="app-loader loader-border app-loader-button"
                    *ngIf="loading">
                        <div class="loader">
                        <div class="la-ball-pulse loaderColor">
                            <div></div>
                            <div></div>
                            <div></div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
                    <button class="btn next-btn float-right error"
                        (click)="goToNext(undefined)" 
                        role="button">Next
                    </button>
                    </div>
                    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

page.ts

```
enableEditing(){
 this.checkEdit = !this.checkEdit;
}

goToNext(customer){
// navigate to another page
}
```

Comment: So you're saying that when you do `(click)="enableEditing()` your actually doing `(click)="goToNext(undefined)"` - and that is the problem? If so then this problem is not coming from this portion of the code. This looks fine.

Comment: Yes this is the problem, but the "goToNext" is called only in this case

Comment: Okay, but like I said, by the looks of the code you supplied it's not happening in this portion of the code you posted (unless you're somehow clicking two buttons at the same time). Open your dev console F12, put break point to `goToNext()` and look up stackTraceTree. Figure out what's calling it or supply rest of the relevant code.

Comment: Is this code in a form that has an onSubmit action? If so try adding the attribute `type="button"` to your buttons.

Comment: @Alex this type="button"  resolves the problem! Ty so much